# URL encode Postman variable?

Tags: postman

I use Postman for REST API testing and parametrize tests with global variables.

I should put a phone number into GET request: `/path/get?phone={{phone}}` but leading `+` sign in the phone number is interpreted as a space.

What is the syntax to URL encode global variables in Postman? Is it possible to run JS `encodeURIComponent()` on variable in URL?

Comment: I opened [an issue to postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7432) to add a flag in the path parameter setup

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use the `Pre-request scripts` (it's next to `body`) for this:

```js
var encoded = encodeURIComponent({{phone number}});
```

or

```js
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(pm.environment.get("phone number"));
```

and to proceed, use:

```js
pm.environment.set("encoded phone number", encoded);
```

And set your URL to `/path/get?phone={{encoded phone number}}`

Comment: Will not this affect the remaining request, will it get corrupted

Comment: I don’t understand the question

Comment: This isn't resulting the results I am expecting. is there a way to see the value of "encoded phone number"? Thanks

Comment: @Eric Open Postman Console (menu -> View -> Show Postman Console / Ctrl+Alt+C), you'll see the request paths with the "encoded phone number".

Answer (score 128):

I am late but still worth it:

Just highlight and right click the part of url you want to encode. Select `encodeURIComponent`

That's it.

[image]

Comment: this is the best way.

Comment: easily the best way

Comment: The question was about variables, that is, stuff like {{defined_someplace_else}}. You can't encode them like that because the value inside that variable needs to be encoded, not the variable reference.

Comment: This is the best way for static parameters. If you try it on a variable in that spot, it encodes the braces that identify it as a variable, not the contents of the variable. Doesn't answer the question (but still helpful for lots of people that find this answer).

Comment: this is the way

Comment: ..did you even read the question?

Answer (score 17):

Just a shortcut to Mohhamad Hasham' answer.

You can encode and decode direct in the Params Value field:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't answer the question of encoding content from variable reference `{{ var }}`. There is no problem to encode static piece of text.

Comment: @gavenkoa you are right - I was misguided by the popular answer that helped me.

Answer (score 10):

The trick is to get your environment variable in the pre-request script and then set it after encoding it

```
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(pm.environment.get("phone"));
    pm.environment.set("encoded phone number", encoded);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are automating Bearer and need encoding you can do this in pre-request script

```
var encodedUser = encodeURIComponent(pm.request.url.query.get("userName"));
var encodedPass = encodeURIComponent(pm.request.url.query.get("userPassword"));

pm.request.url.query.remove("userName");
pm.request.url.query.remove("userPassword");

pm.request.url.query.insert({key:"userName",value: encodedUser});
pm.request.url.query.insert({key:"userPassword",value:encodedPass});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work as well:

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(pm.request.url.query.get("phone"));
pm.request.url.query.remove("phone");
pm.request.url.query.insert("phone", encoded);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the postman version 9.28.4 ==>

You can use 2 methods:

1. By selecting the part of the url in url bar -> right click -> EncodeURLComponent. (screenshot attached)

[image: Demonstration method#1]

2. You can also use "pre-request script" tab of postman and write the script for the variable manually. (screenshot attached)

[image: Demonstration method#2]

Answer (score 2):

The problem with right-click => Encode URI Component is that it destroys the raw value of that parameter. You can use the following pre-request script to overcome this (which also works for cases where you have disabled that param):

```js
// queryParam is of type https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/QueryParam.html
if ((queryParam = pm.request.url.query.one("name_of_your_query_param")) !== undefined
    && queryParam.disabled !== true) {
    queryParam.value = encodeURIComponent(queryParam.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch the toggle on for encoding path and all params in request.
[image: Switch the toggle on]

Comment: In version 10.21.9, this option isn't sufficient: some characters are "forgotten", like the ":" which is not automatically encoded by Postman (tested on a timestamp, format UTC -> "2024-01-10T14:30:45.282Z").

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question looking for an answer to a similar question. For me, the variable was a JSON object. The endpoint I needed to hit was expecting an object list as a query parameter and I have no way to change that to be the request body.

As much as some of the answers helped, I ended up coming up with a combined solution. Also, some of the code given in other answers is outdated as Postman has updated their API over the years, so this uses methods that work on 7.22.1.

```
pm.environment.set("basicJSON", '[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]')
var encoded = encodedURIComponent(pm.environment.get("basicJSON"))
pm.environment.set("encodedJSON", encoded)
```

This solution requires that both `basicJSON` and `encodedJSON` exist as environment variables. But what was important for me was the ease of editing the object. I didn't want to have to decode/encode constantly to change values, and I didn't want to have to open the environment variables dialogue. Also, it's important to note the single-quotes around the object. Excluding them or using double-quotes would cause Postman to send something like `"[object Object]"` which is useless to an endpoint expecting actual JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with braces `{` and `}` in query parameter.
By turning off the following setting it started working for me.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Click the Params button to open the data editor for URL parameters. When you add key-value pairs, Postman combines everything in the query string above. If your URL already has parameters - for example, if you are pasting a URL from some other source. Postman splits the URL into pairs automatically.
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests

Comment: This does not answer the question. These docs describe how to add urlencoded form parameters, whereas the question is about urlencoding GET parameters set from environment variables.