# Gitlab API v4 get tag with slash in name

Tags: gitlab, postman, gitlab-api

I would like to get a Gitlab tag by name using postman. My tag name is release/1.1.8.
I've tried the following URL :

- api/v4/projects/1487/repository/tags/release/1.1.8
- api/v4/projects/1487/repository/tags/release%2F1.1.8

I always get a 404 error. Any idea ?

Comment: Using `%2F` in place of the `/` [works for me](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/34050640/repository/tags/release%2F1.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

URL-encoding `/` to `%2F` is the correct way.

You can see this reproduced here:

https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/34050640/repository/tags/release%2F1.1.8

Make sure [postman is not double-encoding it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253303/5747944).